# Hide cursor everywhere

Tags: c#, mouse-cursor

I'm using C# and wish to hide the cursor globally. I can use Cursor.Hide() to hide the cursor while it is over my application, but I want to hide it completely, no matter where it is. Is this possible?

Comment: yes it is possible but it is an absolutely bad idea... why do you want to do that ?

Comment: Making a screensaver with a transparent form. The mouse is only registered as 'over' the form if it is on a visible part. I wish to hide it no matter where it is.

Comment: Ah, ok. I'm following this tutorial: [link](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/screensaver/screensaver.html) but it is for a screensaver that fills the whole screen, not just a part of it. (And especially not a semi-transparent form!)

Comment: Uh, `Cursor.Hide` works just fine for a screensaver because with a screensaver, your app *is* covering the whole screen. Hiding the cursor when it's over your app is exactly what you need.

Comment: @CodyGray, read my previous comment. I'm using a transparent form. Cursor.Hide only works on opaque sections of the form. Most of the time the cursor isn't hidden. Maybe I could move the cursor onto the opaque section of the form and keep it there, but this seems a bit workaround-ish.

Comment: @Yahia, is there something in User32.dll that I could use? I've used HideCaret before, is there something similar?

Comment: A transparent form is a strange thing to use for a screensaver. The whole point of a screensaver is that it covers the screen. The function that you'd use from user32.dll is [`ShowCursor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648396.aspx) (and passing `FALSE` as the parameter), which is not-so-coincidentally exactly what the `Cursor.Hide` method calls.

Comment: @CodyGray, do you want to post that as an answer so I can mark it as correct? ;)   Also, some screensavers are transparent (like the Win7 Bubble screensaver, or some 3rd party screen destruction ones)
Mine just has a transparent animated logo teleporting around the screen.

Comment: YoshieMaster: They take a screenshot first and use that to draw on. They're not transparent (as you can easily see if you start the screensaver when something is still moving on the screen).

Comment: @Joey, I knew that, but why use a screenshot when it's so easy to use real transparency? It also allows me to see loading progress without exiting the screensaver.

Comment: You suddenly think it answers your question? The answer part says to call `Cursor.Hide`, which is exactly what I suggested in my previous comment and you rejected as not working. And no, those other screensavers are *not* transparent. They draw on top of whatever is currently on the screen at the time that the screensaver is activated. Basically, they *redraw* the current contents of the screen onto an image, and then draw on top of that image. There are very good reasons not to use transparency, far too many to explain in a comment.

Comment: I will reiterate what I have said before.
Cursor.Hide only hides the cursor when it is over an opaque (not transparent) section of the screen. I am assuming that ShowCursor will hide it wherever it is. I will test this soon.
As for not transparency, I quote myself:
@Joey, I knew that, but why use a screenshot when it's so easy to use real transparency? It also allows me to see loading progress without exiting the screensaver.

Comment: **Your assumption is wrong.** My point was that `Cursor.Hide` actually calls the `ShowCursor` function. If the former doesn't work, then the latter won't work. They are identical. It already P/Invoked the `ShowCursor` function for you. Doing it yourself won't help. And no, it's not "easy" to use real transparency. You're not the first person who could have ever thought of this. There's a reason everyone else does it the way they do it.

Comment: @CodyGray, there is absolutely nothing wrong with solving a problem differently. My way has advantages that I like. My way is also simpler to implement. I will take on any challenges associated with that. Yahia said it was possible, they just refrained from telling me because they thought I was using it for nefarious purposes. It can't be *that* hard.

Comment: @Yahia, I haven't figured this out yet, you said it was possible. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: I said that it is possible BUT that it is a very bad idea - that was meant technically AND I haven't changed my mind on that... thus I strongly recommend to follow the advice from @CodyGray with taking a screenshot on screensaver activation etc. !

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are in WPF. You can use:

```
Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.None;
```

to get a transparent cursor for your whole application.